# How to avoid returning a NULL in CASE when one of the three values is NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to thank you in advance for your help on this matter.

I'm writing a SQL query in Oracle SQL Developer which needs to compare 3 dates and return the earliest one, avoiding blank values and writing that value somewhere along the lines.

My question is what do you think is the best way to avoid those NULL values, my take is below but I'm having some slight issues implementing this in my current setup.

Cheers!

```
SELECT Case When DATE1 < DATE2 And DATE1 < DATE3 Then DATE1
            When DATE2 < DATE1 And DATE2 < DATE3 Then DATE2
            Else DATE3
            End AS xxx, SOME.TABLE|| ' ' || TABLE.SOME INTO TABLE1, TABLE2
            
FROM (SELECT Case When DATE1 IS NULL Then DATEADD(year, 100, GETDATE()) Else DATE1 As DATE1,
             Case When DATE2 IS NULL Then DATEADD(year, 100, GETDATE()) Else DATE2 As DATE2,
             Case When DATE3 IS NULL Then DATEADD(year, 100, GETDATE())
             Else DATE3 As DATE3
        FROM SOME_TABLE2 ST2 WHERE SOME_TABLE3 = '#INTO_SOMETHING')
```

Comment: What issues are you have? You said you're using Oracle (SQL Developer, but you tagged Oracle RDBMS); but dateadd and getdate are not Oracle functions. Which *database* are you actually using? Whichever it is, please include sample data and expected results for that data.

Comment: Why not simply write GREATEST(date1,date2,date3) or LEAST(date1,date2,date3) instead of this case when?

Comment: Also what do you want to happen when all three dates are null - should that then return null (which seems sensible), or your dummy future date (today but 100 years in the future in your current code)?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Correct, my syntax is wrong as dateadd and getdate are not Oracle functions like Alex mentioned (this was my issue probably). When all three values are null it should return null, not my dummy future date. 

I'm only a beginner so apologies for any inconveniences. 
I've been able to get it working with below suggestion using LEAST and COALESCE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEAST` and `COALESCE`:

```sql
SELECT LEAST(
         COALESCE(date1, date2, date3, ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 100*12)),
         COALESCE(date2, date3, date1, ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 100*12)),
         COALESCE(date3, date1, date2, ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 100*12))
       ) AS least_date
FROM   table_name;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
         LEAST(
           COALESCE(date1, date2, date3),
           COALESCE(date2, date3, date1),
           COALESCE(date3, date1, date2)
         ),
         ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 100*12)
       ) AS least_date
FROM   table_name;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT LEAST(
         COALESCE(date1, ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 100*12)),
         COALESCE(date2, ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 100*12)),
         COALESCE(date3, ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 100*12))
       ) AS least_date
FROM   table_name;
```

*Note: the first two queries will return the least non-`NULL` value from your table in preference to the default value 100 years from now. The final query may return the default value 100 years from now if all the other values are a mix of `NULL` and non-`NULL` values that are greater than 100 years from now. Which you use depends on the logic you want to implement and whether your table will ever contain dates more than 100 years in the future.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date1, date2, date3) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', NULL, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2021-01-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, DATE '2021-01-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| LEAST_DATE |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2122-12-05 09:50:28 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IZ4X0FEz)

---

If you do want a `NULL` value if, and only if, all 3 dates are `NULL` then use the first query without the default date:

```sql
SELECT LEAST(
         COALESCE(date1, date2, date3),
         COALESCE(date2, date3, date1),
         COALESCE(date3, date1, date2)
       ) AS least_date
FROM   table_name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8XDQ5Fr6)

Comment: Awesome, this one actually worked in my setup and I'm able to get results by using LEAST and COALESCE! I'll fiddle around with these functions to avoid getting my future dummy date when all three values are NULL (right now I'm getting my future date as a result of 3 blank values).

Comment: @Dino I've added an update for if you want `NULL` when all 3 dates are `NULL` (and a non-null in other cases).

Comment: Good deal, thank you for the speedy resolution. Appreciate it.

Comment: It's a nuisance that `LEAST` and `GREATEST` result in NULL when at least one value is null in Oracle. In PostgreSQL and SQL Server, they only result in NULL when all values are null (just like 'MIN' and `MAX`). There we would just write `LEAST(date1, date2, date3)` which is simpler and much more intuitive in my opinion.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In this case yes, that would be simpler but if you consider `NULL` to represent an unknown value then semantically having the output of `LEAST(known, unknown, known) = unknown` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little paralel results Using LEAST() function alone, with Nvl() and CASE with Nvl. The Last one will return Null if all 3 date columns are Null.
Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl As 
        (
            Select 1 "NMBR", 'A' "LTTR", SYSDATE "DATE1", SYSDATE-1 "DATE2", SYSDATE+1 "DATE3" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "NMBR", 'B' "LTTR", SYSDATE "DATE1", SYSDATE-1 "DATE2", Null "DATE3" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "NMBR", 'C' "LTTR", SYSDATE "DATE1", Null "DATE2", SYSDATE+1 "DATE3" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "NMBR", 'D' "LTTR", Null "DATE1", SYSDATE-1 "DATE2", SYSDATE+1 "DATE3" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "NMBR", 'E' "LTTR", Null "DATE1", Null "DATE2", SYSDATE+1 "DATE3" From Dual Union All
            Select 6 "NMBR", 'F' "LTTR", Null "DATE1", Null "DATE2", NULL "DATE3" From Dual 
        )
```

| NMBR | LTTR | DATE1 | DATE2 | DATE3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 05-DEC-22 | 04-DEC-22 | 06-DEC-22 |
| 2 | B | 05-DEC-22 | 04-DEC-22 |  |
| 3 | C | 05-DEC-22 |  | 06-DEC-22 |
| 4 | D |  | 04-DEC-22 | 06-DEC-22 |
| 5 | E |  |  | 06-DEC-22 |
| 6 | F |  |  |  |

SQL

```sql
SELECT 
    NMBR,
    LTTR,
    LEAST(DATE1, DATE2, DATE3) "LEAST_DATE",
    LEAST(Nvl(DATE1, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000), Nvl(DATE2, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000), Nvl(DATE3, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000)) "LEAST_NVL_DATE",
    CASE  
          WHEN LEAST(Nvl(DATE1, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000), Nvl(DATE2, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000), Nvl(DATE3, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000)) < TRUNC(SYSDATE+1000) 
          THEN LEAST(Nvl(DATE1, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000), Nvl(DATE2, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000), Nvl(DATE3, TRUNC(SYSDATE)+10000))
    END "LEAST_CASE_NVL_DATE"
FROM
  tbl
```

Result:

| NMBR | LTTR | LEAST_DATE | LEAST_NVL_DATE | LEAST_CASE_NVL_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 04-DEC-22 | 04-DEC-22 | 04-DEC-22 |
| 2 | B |  | 04-DEC-22 | 04-DEC-22 |
| 3 | C |  | 05-DEC-22 | 05-DEC-22 |
| 4 | D |  | 04-DEC-22 | 04-DEC-22 |
| 5 | E |  | 06-DEC-22 | 06-DEC-22 |
| 6 | F |  | 22-APR-50 |  |

Comment: Your second answer is exactly the same as my third answer(ignoring that you are adding 10,000 days and not 100 years) and should have exactly the same caveats as I listed in my answer. The third answer seems slightly strange and does not work when the column dates are future values [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QU6MEzy_).

Comment: This was just a paralel sample (there were no sample data in the question) what happens if LEAST is used in different ways, and the person who would use it would know the data and just pushed the dates further in the future (like you did in the fiddle - just further more)...

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve the issue by using LEAST and COALESCE functions, since DATEADD and GETDATE are not Oracle functions.

Further to this, I've used @MT0 resolution query which worked well in my current setup.

Comment: Then accept MT0's answer by checking the tick next to it.

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out, it's not very intuitive to be fair.
His answer is accepted now!